# Accent diesel car battery type

Tags: battery, fuel-system, diesel, accent

My old car battery (Exide Express) is totally dead.   Now I am buying a new battery. I want to know which battery is the best battery for my car (diesel 2002 model). My car model is a Hyundai Accent diesel 2002 heater engine. I already Googled battery types. There are Exide Max, Exide Mattrix , and mine was an Exide Express. Can you please tell me the difference from this battery? My car self start drains more battery when self start. Please suggest a more powerful Exide battery which will work for me.

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

*Exide* is simply a battery manufacturer. The *Max*, *Matrix*, and *Express* are just marketing names for some of their battery lines. The best battery to get is one that fits your car, and will last an appropriate length of time for the cost.

If your battery is not being properly recharged, it's also possible that your alternator is bad, or is going bad. Both the battery and alternator will wear out over time. Batteries typically last a few years, depending on a few factors. If you want a battery that will last longer, spend more and get an AGM (absorbed glass mat) battery.

Take your vehicle to the local parts store, have both the alternator and battery tested, and replace what needs to be replaced.

Comment: i tested my alternator .. i was working good as mechanic said. and told me battery is dead ... in here exide service is much better than other battery makers. can you please explain me more about AGM  or which model come with AGM thank you

Comment: AGM tend to last longer as they use fiberglass mats that have been saturated with the dielectric, rather than just being a sealed lead acid battery, and can fit more plates into the same area. This helps them last longer. Exide might have a batter line that is AGM, but I don't know which one it is.